# Change ruby hash to jsonl - JSON seperated by newlines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rest, api

I am looking at posting to an endpoint on Bubble.io using Ruby and they require jsonl (plain text, new-line seperated) instead of JSON.

Is there a way to take a hash and make it jsonl? Something like hash.to_jsonl.

Comment: What you've asked here, and what you've posted below, aren't the same thing. You asked how to make a **hash** into JSONL, for which there is no answer. The answer you provided below turns an array of hashes into JSONL, which is trivial, since JSONL is simply a series of smaller JSON documents separated by newlines.

Answer (score 4):

For jsonl (or ndjson), the json need to be formated as single line.
Therefor use to_json method.

```
require 'json'

group = [{:name => "Tom", :age => 27}, {:name => "Jerry", :age => 37}]
puts group.map { |r| JSON.generate(r) }.join("\n")
```

This code generates the following:

```
{"name":"Tom","age":27}
{"name":"Jerry","age":37}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I went with:

```
group = [{name => "Tom"}, {name => "Jerry"}]
generated = []

group.each do |r|
    generated << JSON.generate(r)
end

jsonl_text = generated.join("\n")
```

Comment: You can make this more idiomatically Ruby by using `map` instead of `each`. `jsonl_text = group.map { |r| JSON.generate(r) }.join("\n")`